# I don't understand this usage of "as"

Tags: word-usage, relative-pronouns, as

- One week later Roosevelt embargoed the export of such grades of oil as still were in commercial flow to Japan.

I don't understand this usage of "as".  Is it the same as "which"?  Or is it the same as "because"?  Could you please paraphrase this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

We use '*such as*' to introduce an example, and this can be done in different ways:

- I like fruit, **such as** apples.
- I like **such** apples **as** Granny Smith and Golden Delicious.

In your example, the words have just become a little more separated because of the length of the compound noun '*grades of oil*'. It means that the *kind* of oil grades embargoed were the ones in commercial flow to Japan.

Comment: I've seen many examples of "such as" followed by nouns, but i n this case, it is followed by a sentence without the subject.